# Can array_search return the second index if search value exists more than once in array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to modify array_search() so that it returns the second index if the search value is found more than once in the array?

Here's my example :

```
$barcode = '9815';

$product = array ([product_id] => 9815 [sale] => on [barcode] => 9815);

$key = array_search($barcode, $product); 

echo $key;
```

**Output**

```
 product_id
```

How would could I rewrite the above so that if the `$barcode` value is found more than once in the array, it returns the `barcode` index rather than the `product_id` index ?

Any advice would be great - thanks

Comment: Minus? Doesn't seem called for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_reverse` before `array_search`

```
<?php
$barcode = '9815';

$product = array ("product_id" => 9815, "sale" => "on", "barcode" => 9815);

$key = array_search($barcode, array_reverse($product)); 
print_r(array_reverse($product));
echo $key;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - your solution suits my requirements better than the solution given in the marked duplicated question.

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't. Instead you would use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with its optional argument(s) and take it from there, e.g.:

```
$product = array ('product_id' => 9815, 'sale' => 'on', 'barcode' => 9815);
$key = array_keys($barcode, $product); 
echo $key[1];
```